# Can you use the Metamagic option Extended Spell more than once on a single spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, sorcerer, metamagic, duration

Can you use the sorcerer's Metamagic option Extended Spell more than once on a single spell? In other words, can you pay more SP to extend the duration by one factor?

For example:
Say a given spell has a duration of 1 minute. If you spend 1 Sorcery Point, the duration changes to 10 minutes; spending 3 SP changes the duration to 1 hour; 4 SP makes it 8 Hours; 5 SP makes it 24 hours. Does this work?

Comment: why would spending 1SP extend from 1min to 10min? Per Extended Spell spending 1SP would extend from 1min to 2min.

Comment: To put it differently, what source are you getting that definition of Extended Spell from?

Answer (score 30):

No, you can't. In general, you can only use one metamagic, once, on any spell.

> You
>   can
>   use
>   only
>   one
>   Metamagic
>   option
>   on
>   a
>   spell
>   when
>   you
>   cast
>   it,
>   unless
>   otherwise
>   noted.

The *only* such note is this one, on Empowered Spell:

> You
>   can
>   use
>   Empowered
>   Spell
>   even
>   if
>   you
>   have
>   already
>   used
>   a
>   different
>   Metamagic
>   option
>   during
>   the
>   casting
>   of
>   the
>   spell.

In particular, Extended Spell has no such note.

> When
>   you
>   cast
>   a
>   spell
>   that
>   has
>   a
>   duration
>   of
>   1
>   minute
>   or
>   longer,
>   you
>   can
>   spend
>   1
>   sorcery
>   point
>   to
>   double
>   its
>   duration,
>   to
>   a
>   maximum
>   duration
>   of
>   24
>   hours.

So no, you can only Extend a spell once. Also, Extended Spell doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. All it does is double the duration, not increase the duration by "factors".

Answer (score 10):

### No, you can only use a metamagic option once per spell.

This question is explicitly addressed in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=6) ([here on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA051)):

> **Metamagic rules state you can’t use multiple Metamagic options on a single spell. Can you use one option multiple times?**
>
> A sorcerer can use one Metamagic option once in the casting of a spell, not the same option more than once. For instance, a sorcerer can’t quadruple the duration of a spell by spending 2 sorcery points on Extended Spell.

This fits with the explicitly stated restriction (in the description of the [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) feature) that you can use only one Metamagic option on a spell when you cast it; likewise, you can only use that option once on a spell you cast (it doesn't stack with itself).

Answer (score 6):

## The intent is No

Jeremy Crawford says [that is not the intention of the Metamagic](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/18/can-sorcerer-use-multiple-metamagic-on-spells/).

> **Revenant_Fury** *@Revenant_Fury*
>
> *@JeremyECrawford* Metamagic rules state you can't use multiple Metamagic options on a single spell. Can you use one option, multiple times?
>
> 11:17 AM - 7 Aug 2015
>
> ---
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** *@JeremyECrawford*
>
> The intent is that a sorcerer can use a Metamagic option once with a spell, not the same option more than once. [https://twitter.com/Revenant_Fury/status/629491521872633856 …](https://t.co/7iofA0d62k)
>
> 1:39 PM - 7 Aug 2015

## However, RAW does not seem to restrict it

The following rule forbids you from using Quickened Spell and Extended Spell on the same casting, because QS and TS are different options.

> You can use only one Metamagic **option** on a spell when you cast it, unless otherwise noted.

It does **not** say: *you can **apply** only one Metamagic **effect** on a spell when you cast it, unless otherwise noted* or any similar language which generally forbids more than one application of a Metamagic ability on a spell; only the prevention of using more than one Metamagic option.

Extended Spell is the same Metamagic *option* as Extended Spell (obviously). The rules apply only when the options are different. RAW does not forbid you from stacking Extended Spell on the same casting.

Comment: It depends on how strict or loose your interpretation.  You are allowed to use one option.  The option you choose allows you to spend one sorcery point to double the duration.  It does not allow you to spend two points to quadruple it, etc.

Comment: @NickBrown if you use one option twice, you _"use only one Metamagic option on a spell"_.