# Is it possible through established game mechanics to extend the duration of Alter Self to 12-24 hours?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I have a Crowley-esque character (the demon from Supernatural) who is concerned about *ehem* certain features, and this is exactly the kind of petty nonsense this character would do. I'm looking for a way without endless scrolls that the duration of Alter Self could be cast only once or twice a day, preferably that could take out the concentration component as well.

Comment: Is it important that he casts it only a few times, or is the aim that he can keep it up indefinitely?

Comment: Does your character have a race yet or are you looking for options post-creation?

Comment: Also, are you a player or the DM here?

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get is with the warlock invocation *master of myriad forms*, that lets you cast *alter self* at will. It still requires concentration and you have to refresh it every hour. It also needs you to have at least 15 warlock levels.

If levels are at a premium, but only the illusion of a different shape is enough for most of the time, you can go with *mask of many faces*, that requires only 2 warlock levels and lets you cast *disguise self* at will. If you take another 3 levels in sorcerer, you will be able to sustain *alter self* for 4 hours with the *extended spell* metamagic.

If you are the DM making an NPC, I recommend you just grant them the spell at will or base them on a shapeshifter fiend. It is unlikely to unbalance anything and might add nice flavor to the character. Also, neither at will low level spells or shapeshifting is rare in fiends, so you could consider it an "established mechanic". As far as that can go for a custom NPC anyway.

Answer (score -3):

This is going to be a tough thing to achieve, and some will argue that you cannot do it in the way that you would like.  I say you can, but I bet I get comments otherwise.

Once or twice a day can, AFAIK, only be achieved by having the Sorcerer Metamagic *Extended Spell*.  You'll need to get DM buy-in on this, as it isn't fully clear, but I read *Extended Spell* as allowing multiple Sorcery Points to be spent to extend a spell, up to a maximum of 24 hours.  If your DM agrees, then you will need to take 4 or 5 levels of Sorcerer, take the *Extended Spell* Metamagic, and cast *Alter Self* using 4 Sorcery Points for a 16-hour duration (and hide in your coffin the other 8), or 5 Sorcery Points for the full 24 hours.

Removing the concentration component is more difficult, and  will require some effort and preparation.  You will need to cast a *Glyph of Warding* (which takes an hour to cast, and is not mobile once cast) with the extended *Alter Self* in it, then trigger it to cast the spell on yourself.  Being able to do this will require taking 5 levels of Bard, Cleric, or Wizard.

The other option, which is kind of close to the effect you want, is to be a Warlock and get the Invocation of *Mask of Many Faces* at 2nd level, and switch it for *Master of Myriad Forms* at 15th level.  This method is straightforward, but would still require concentration.  That would let you operate a normal life with a different appearance, but would risk dropping that appearance under certain conditions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about whether one can multiply-extend a spell with sorcery points has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72423/discussion-on-answer-by-phil-boncer-is-it-possible-through-established-game-mech).

Comment: This is an interesting way of looking at metamagic. Expending more points to increase Extended is an interesting idea, do you see it working the same for Distant?

Comment: [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97506/23970) on whether extend can be applied more than once to the same spell

Comment: @NautArch -- I could see that being argued either way.  I would probably say "yes", since my natural inclination is to let characters do things creatively.  But the *Distant* Metamagic does not have a maximum range listed that would imply being able to double the spell up to that range, so it's purely a coinflip/judgement call.  The particular thing that tends me to think that works with *Extend* is that it says you can double it with an SP, up to a maximum of 24 hours.  That implies to me that you may double it multiple times, up to that point.

Comment: Good point on the maximum range bit. While I think the Extend is less likely to be cheesed, Distant could create a cheese problem if allowed (but, as you said, there's a reason to NOT allow it while still allowing it for Extend.)

Comment: The rules clearly spell out that you can only use one metamagic option per spell casting.  The extended spell metamagic allows you to spend a single sorcery point to double the spell's duration (once).  You are reading beyond the rules (and no longer following them) by choosing to use the same option multiple times.  If you were meant to have this ability the rules would clearly spell it out.

Comment: Spending multiple points on *Extend* does not necessarily violate the rule against using more than one Metamagic option.  I would say that you are still using only one option, to extend the spell's duration, and choosing how many points to spend for how much to extend it.  AGAIN, I noted that not everyone would run it that way, and that he would need DM buy-in to do this, so I am aware of the issue, and do not need dogmatic chiding about it.  If you disagree, then run it your way on your world.  That doesn't mean everyone has to do it your way.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't look it up right now but I remember reading a tweet from Jeremy E Crawford sayin you cant apply the same metamagic multiple times.

Comment: AGAIN, I noted that not everyone would run it that way, and that he would need DM buy-in to do this, so I am aware of the issue. If you disagree, then run it your way on your world. That doesn't mean everyone has to do it your way.