# Holding a delayed blast fireball bead without moving

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If someone successfully picks up a bead of a delayed blast fireball, must they throw it immediately or can they hold onto it for as long as the spell's duration before it explodes?

[Delayed blast fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/delayed-blast-fireball):

> A beam of yellow light flashes from your pointing finger, then condenses to linger at a chosen point within range as a glowing bead for the duration. [...] If the glowing bead is touched before the interval has expired, the creature touching it must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the spell ends immediately, causing the bead to erupt in flame. On a successful save, the creature can throw the bead up to 40 feet.

I understand a bead cannot be moved based on the language that specifically states the bead "lingers at a chosen point [...] for the duration."  I'm not concerned about trying to pick up and run with the bead.  I'm asking whether the bead can remain picked up by a stationary bearer for multiple rounds.

Based on the wording of the spell, it does not seem like the creature must throw it immediately.

This is not the same question as the following: [Can I carry a bead of Delayed Blast Fireball in a flask and then throw it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140721/can-i-carry-a-bead-of-delayed-blast-fireball-in-a-flask-and-then-throw-it)

Comment: You understand the bead cannot be moved. Picking up the bead clearly moves it (not on a 5'x5' grid, but you *picked it up*). Where is the confusion?

Comment: Are there any rules against picking up the bead and holding it for 9 rounds before throwing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The spell does not say, you likely throw it right away

All the spell says is:

> On a successful save, the creature can throw the bead up to 40 feet.

It does not say you must throw it immediately. It also does not say you can hold onto it and throw it anytime before the spell ends and it automatically explodes. Therefore, this is up to your DM.

I think it is more likely that you would need to throw it immediately. There is also the spell *Otiluke's freezing sphere*, that allows you to create a small globe of a frost area damage effect, and that says:

> You can refrain from firing the globe after completing the spell, if you wish. A small globe about the size of a sling stone, cool to the touch, appears in your hand. **At any time**, you or a creature you give the globe to can throw the globe (to a range of 40 feet) or hurl it with a sling (to the sling's normal range). It shatters on impact, with the same effect as the normal casting of the spell. You can also set the globe down without shattering it. **After 1 minute**, if the globe hasn't already shattered, it explodes.

If the intent was to be able to throw the bead at any time after touching it, and the editing was consistent, then delayed blast fireball also would need to say *at any time* for you to be able to hold onto the bead between saving and throwing. However, this is assumes a consistency in editing that the rules often do not have, and one example to go by is not a lot.

There are no general rules that the effects of a saving throw must be immediate, although they usually are. For example, the poison Midnight Tears will damage you at midnight. You make that saving throw at midnight, not when you ingest the poison. The general rules for saving throws however only say (*PH* p. 180)

> The result of a successful or failed saving throw is also detailed in the effect that allows the save.

So because the effect does not detail it, and it can be interpreted in different ways, it is up to the DM.

Leaving things up to the DM is a conscious design decision by the authors of 5e, to make the game more playable. This is explained in *Xanathar‘s Guide to Everything*, p. 4:

> The DM is key. Many unexpected events can occur in a D&D campaign, and no set of rules could reasonably account for every contingency. If the rules tried to do so, the game would become a slog. An alternative would be for the rules to severely limit what characters can do, which would be contrary to the open-endedness of D&D. Here's the path the game takes: it lays a foundation of rules that a DM can build on, and it embraces the DM's role as the bridge between the things the rules address and the things they don't.

Comment: When I first saw this question, *Freezing Sphere* was the spell I thought about: but I think that it is exactly the counterexample that proves that Delaued fireball cannot be picked up and carried away

Comment: Freezing sphere is instant, you don't get chance to do much else with it. Delayed fireball lingers for several rounds. I really don't understand these interpretations. It is pretty clearly meant to be moved and held until it is primed, just dangerous to do so

Comment: Nob the Hob, I added some relevant part of *Freezing Sphere*'s description that shows that there are some common points between the spells. I believe that adding those details strengthen your reasoning.

Comment: @Eddymage Thank you