# Does the sorcerer's Extended Spell metamagic option extend the duration of a spell exponentially or linearly?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spellcasting, metamagic, duration

When it mentions that you can spend 1 sorcery point to double its duration, up to a maximum of 24 hours, does it mean that every time you spend a sorcery point you add the original duration again? Or does it exponentially double the duration?

For example, if I spend 4 sorcery points on a 1 minute spell, does it become 5 minutes (1 minute duration added four times) or 16 minutes long (1 minute doubled four times)?

What I meant by this question is just using Extended Spell on a spell once, but using more than 1 sorcery point on it as per the metamagic's description.

I know you can't re-extend a spell if it's already active, but I'm talking about the initial casting, where you can spend multiple sorcery points to double the spell's duration.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: A related/similar question: "[Can you use Extended Spell Metamagic more than once?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97506)"

Comment: Hi, I've rearranged the paragraphs so that it asks the question first and clarifies the question afterwards. Still all your words, just a different order. If you don't like my reordering, feel free to [edit] it into a different order (or even rollback my edit entirely). Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use Extended Spell Metamagic more than once?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97506/can-you-use-extended-spell-metamagic-more-than-once)

Answer (score 20):

## Extended Spell only extends the duration once by doubling it.

A caster can't use Extended Spell multiple times on the same casting, and the feature doesn't accommodate using multiple sorcery points at once.

### This is addressed directly in the Sage Advice Compendium

At the bottom of [page 5 of version 2.4 of the SAC](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=5), it says:

> **Metamagic rules state you can’t use multiple Metamagic options on a single spell. Can you use one option multiple times?**
>
> A sorcerer can use one Metamagic option once in the casting of a spell, not the same option more than once. For instance, a sorcerer can’t quadruple the duration of a spell by spending 2 sorcery points on Extended Spell.

This is further discussed in this Q&A: [Can you use Extended Spell Metamagic more than once?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97506/can-you-use-extended-spell-metamagic-more-than-once)

### Can't pump more sorcery points through Extend Spell

The wording is that you can spend one point.

> When you cast a spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double its duration...

A wording that would have permitted multiple points would be "...for every point spent.." or "... can spend 2 sorcery points to quadruple it's duration and so on..."

Comment: Hmm. This Q might be a dupe of the one you linked, don't you think so?

Comment: hmm, I'd thought extended spell had the clause that allowed you to use multiple sorcery points on the spell you're extending, and you're still using it once, not multiple times